# How to upgrade libstdc++.so on Colab runtime?

Tags: c++, google-colaboratory

I would like to run on Colab a C++ library which requires a version of libstdc++.so which is newer than the one provided by the default g++ 7.x installed on Colab. Such requirement is due to C++17 features not supported by g++ 7.x.

In order to do so, I install a recent g++ compiler (and corresponding libstdc++.so) from a PPA. However, when I try to import libraries compiled with the updated g++ compiler it seems that the python runtime is not aware of the update to libstdc++.so, unless one restarts the runtime via "Runtime -> Restart runtime".

Since restarting the runtime is an ugly workaround, and might be disruptive for my end users, is there a better way to make the current runtime aware that libstdc++.so has changed?

I have prepared a [standalone notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ki3sWDfXPzYfNOuAY5TftVxpTOLEKw0m) which shows my problem on a simple case (using pybind11).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install and use recent libstdc++ do:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
2. `sudo apt install libstdc++-9-dev`.
3. Installed include files are inside `/usr/include/c++/9/` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/`.
4. Installed binary library files (.a/.so) are in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/`.
5. You  can list installed files of package through `dpkg -L libstdc++-9-dev`.

Now you can run your program like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ your_program_name
```

So that it gets correct path and correct .so file.

Issue with your Notebook was solved for me by adding to `setup.py` following options, after that your Notebook doesn't print any error:

```
extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", '-static', '-static-libgcc', '-static-libstdc++'],
extra_link_args=['-static-libgcc', '-static-libstdc++'],
```

Also you can collect all necessary .so files into folder of your Python's module and package all into wheel .whl file. There is no need to APT-install all .so dependencies on every machine. I think for Python is more clean solution to ship all necessary .so files inside .whl.

Comment: Thanks. That is basically what I am doing already in my notebook, but it seems that it is not enough (see the second to last cell).

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin If you get same results like me, meaning that correct .so file is located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/` folder then what doesn't work for you? You can just use this path directly when running your program like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ your_program_name`.

Comment: I am afraid that's not the point. My third to last cell already shows that your use case is indeed working, but that's not what I am actually looking for. My main goal is indeed shown in my second to last cell: I am not trying to run an external program, I am trying to import a library (compiled with C++, and wrapped to python) in the current colab runtime.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin I see your program's error is `libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found` so it means that actually you have problem not with libstdc++, but with incorrect version of GLIBC, it is a different library.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Also, is it possible for you to recompile this program again? Then you can provide correct fixed libraries versions. Or you got this program from somewhere and you can't recompile it?

Comment: The final goal (not shown in this notebook) would be to package elsewhere the actual library and ship it for later use on Colab, so I cannot recompile it on the fly on Colab.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Why don't you do static linking of all libraries? GCC has param `-static`. So that you have final binary that doesn't depend on any .so file. Everything is included in single binary.

Comment: > so it means that actually you have problem not with libstdc++, but with incorrect version of GLIBC, it is a different library

Thanks. I am not quite sure what you mean here, especially considering that upon runtime restart (which is a workaround I want to avoid!) the problem disappears.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Please read last comment above.

Comment: The complete library would be part of a very complex pipeline of C++ libraries (20 dependencies or so, which I the reason why it is not affordable to recompile every time on Colab, as it would take hours), some of that wrapped with pybind11. I cannot say how easy/difficult it would be to inject -static in each of them. We have experience in packaging them without -static, and if possible we'd like to stick with that.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Please put a [look here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u4EKDmqnjD4wjspGKgxm3Y_O0NaSNqBj?usp=sharing), I modified your Notebook, added static linking just of standard libraries libstdc++ and glibc. It seems to work now for me, at least there is no error. I added `'-static-libgcc', '-static-libstdc++'` to setup.py. Now you can link all your own libraries dynamically while standard libraries will be linked statically.

Comment: Thanks Arty, I have slightly rephrased the opening post to say "import libraries" rather than "load libraries", which hopefully may make some of our comments more clear for future users reading this question.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Does my [modified notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u4EKDmqnjD4wjspGKgxm3Y_O0NaSNqBj?usp=sharing) solve your issue or it is not what you want? This notebook doesn't print any error anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look then at out easy/difficult it is to add `'-static-libgcc', '-static-libstdc++'` in the pipeline that builds the 20 dependencies (it might not be easy, but at least that's a starting point). Feel free to edit the answer mentioning this change to my notebook, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Already added this solving-change to end of my answer. You can accept it now.

Comment: @FrancescoBallarin Also you may copy all .so files to one folder, where your Python's package is located, then run your program as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. program_name`. There is no need for you to APT install all .so files, just copy reference .so files to final package's folder and ship this archive as wheel .whl file.